# Install error with Aptana Studio 3 on CentOS 5 (glibc version)

Tags: aptana, glibc, centos5

On a CentOS 5 server, I have downloaded and unzipped Aptana Studio 3. When I run it, the IDE opens properly but generates an error and ask to close.

The error is the following:

```
!SESSION 2011-10-13 16:25:43.255 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-10-13 16:25:46.561
!MESSAGE Unable to find Action Set: com.aptana.editor.php.presentation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2011-10-13 16:26:19.394
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handlesNative code library failed to load. (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.1295409059/os/linux/x86/libcefjni.so: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /usr/local/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.1295409059/os/linux/x86/libcefjni.so))
```

and here is the answer to rpm -qi glibc:

```
Name        : glibc                        Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2.5                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 65                            Build Date: Fri 12 Aug 2011 01:49:31 PM EDT
Install Date: Wed 14 Sep 2011 01:31:47 AM EDT      Build Host: builder10.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: glibc-2.5-65.src.rpm
Size        : 12971036                         License: LGPL
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Fri 12 Aug 2011 05:24:55 PM EDT, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
Summary     : The GNU libc libraries.
```

Any way to work around that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed that plugin (com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_1.0.0.1295409059) from the plugins directory.  The aptana studio startup web page doesn't work, but I haven't had a problem with regular editing yet.